Lower bounding a sumset quantity
Given $A,B \subset[0,...,d]^n$ such that $A \cap B = \phi$. Can we show
$$ |(2A \cup 2B) \triangle (A + B)| \geq \Omega_d({\rm poly}(|A|,|B|))$$
where $2A = A+A, 2B = B+B$ and we are taking the minkowski sum. Also note that $\triangle$ is the symmetric difference.
There are results which show that $|A+B| \geq \Omega_d({\rm poly}(|A|,|B|))$ as illustrated in Estimate of Minkowski sum. Thus if $|A| << |B|$ then $2A \cup 2B$ will dominate $A+B$ and we have
$$|(2A \cup 2B) \triangle (A + B)| \geq \Omega_d({\rm poly}(|A|,|B|)).$$
The interesting case is when $|A| \sim |B|$, where we can't use techniques as before. Any help in solving this question would be appreciated.
Edit: Changed $A,B \subset [0,...,d]$ to $A,B\subset [0,...,d]^n$. You can think of d as an absolute constant like $d = 5$ if it helps.

We may slightly modify Ilya Bogdanov's idea by taking, say, $A=\{0, 1, 3, 4, 8\pmod {10}\}$,  $B=\{2, 5, 6, 7, 9\pmod {10}\}$ in $[0,d]$.

Let $A$ contain all numbers congruent to $0,1,3\mod 6$ and $B$ contain all numbers congruent to $2,4,5\mod 6$. Then the symmetric difference appears only near the ends of $[0,2d]$.

Hi ! I was going through the counter-example once again and I think the above set is not the correct counter-example. Since $2A \cup 2B= {a \in [0:2d] | a \mod{6} \in {0,1,2,3,4}  }$ and $A+B = {a \in [0:2d] | a \mod(6) \in {0,1,2,3,4,5 } }$. Thus symmetric difference will have around $d/3$ elements.

You can replace 6 to 100 and take a random partition of remainders mod 100 onto two classes. With probability almost 1 both sets $A+A, A+B$ contain all remainders

@FedorPetrov if possible can you expand on this calculation. This would be very helpful to me.

Well, you may take A=0 1 3 4 8, B=2 5 6 7 9 modulo 10.

Thank you @FedorPetrov. If you write up the example as an answer I would accept your answer.
